# Correct parameter type for moving object into vector

Tags: c++, move, stdvector, move-semantics

Suppose I have an object that holds some data:

```
struct Object
{
   std::vector<float> data;
}
```

And a struct that holds some objects:

```
struct Holder 
{
   private:
   std::vector<Object> objects_;
}
```

Calling code wants to build an Object and add it to a Holder without creating copies as Object may contain millions of elements. My initial thought was to let Holder handle the move:

```
struct Holder 
{
   void addObject(Object& object)
   {
      objects_.push_back(std::move(object));
   }
   private:
   std::vector<Object> objects_;
}
```

However, other programmers may not be aware that the object it passed to Holder::addObject will leave it in an unspecified state and continue to work on it. Thus, I leave it to calling code to explicitly move the object into a copy, else a copy is constructed:

```
struct Holder 
{
   void addObject(Object object)
   {
      objects_.push_back(std::move(object));
   }
   private:
   std::vector<Object> objects_;
}
```

Calling code then looks like:

```
Holder h;
Object o;
// populate c

h.addObject(std::move(o))
```

Is the use of std::move in this context correct? Is there an alternative, more correct and obvious way of handling this?

Comment: Make `Object` movable but not copyable and compiler will tell you if you do something wrong

Answer (score 3):

You could emplace the construction of your objects into the holder's vector. This also allows for passing a rvalue (which can be moved from).

```
template<typename... Args>
void emplaceObject (Args... && args) {
  objects_.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward)  forwards the value category of the parameters, that is if you called your function with an rvalue, then the `std::vector:: emplace_back()` will also get an rvalue.

So `h.emplaceObject(std::move(o))` would call the move constructor of `Object` once.

Btw, this is called [perfect forwarding.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3582001/1116364)